# Detect how long a sound is in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the audio metering in AVFoundation and I wanted to know if there's a way to figure out how long a sound is.  I have my audio recorder setup like this:

```
func startMeterTimer() {
    levelTimer?.invalidate()
    levelTimer = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: "updateMeter")
    levelTimer?.frameInterval = 5
    levelTimer?.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
}

func stopMeterTimer() {
    levelTimer?.invalidate()
    levelTimer = nil
}

func updateMeter() {
    readLevels()
    let avgPower = audioRecorder?.averagePowerForChannel(0)
    let peakPower = audioRecorder?.peakPowerForChannel(0)

    if peakPower >= -2 {
        print("CLAP DETECTED")
        soundLogicDelegate?.clapDetected()
    }
 //        print("\(avgPower) + \(peakPower)")
}

func record() -> Bool {
    return (audioRecorder?.record())!
}
```

record and startMeterTImer are called and when I clap my hand, even though I only clap once, I get many print statements of CLAP DETECTED.  I was wondering if there was a way to measure how long a method is called from the first time it's called and the last time it's called.

Comment: How about using `NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording` delegate method, one of it's parameters is an instance of `AVAudioRecorder`  which has `currentTime` property:

> The time, in seconds, since the beginning of the recording.
>   (read-only)

If you want to check recording time each time `updateMeter()` is called use `audioRecorder?.currentTime`

Comment: I don't know think that'll work since i'm constantly recording waiting for sounds from the user whether it be clap or blowing into the mic.  So I actually never call stop recording.