# Detecting Talking with swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I have an app that needs to detect when the user is talking to the app. I don't want to have any third party APIs. I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562977/detect-how-long-a-sound-is-in-ios) turtorial, but I had to convert it to swift 2. This is the code that I am using:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import CoreAudio

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {

var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder?

var timer = NSTimer()

@IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {
    if audioRecorder?.recording == false {
        audioRecorder?.record()
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.checkForAudio), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}


@IBAction func stop(sender: AnyObject) {
    if audioRecorder?.recording == true {
        audioRecorder?.stop()
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}


func checkForAudio() {
    audioRecorder?.updateMeters()

    print("Average: \(audioRecorder?.averagePowerForChannel(0)) Peak: \(audioRecorder?.peakPowerForChannel(0))")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let fileMgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let dirPaths = fileMgr.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentationDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    let soundFileURL = dirPaths[0].URLByAppendingPathComponent("sound.caf")

    let recordSettings = [AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0, AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2, AVEncoderBitRateKey: 12800, AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16, AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue]

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("audioSession error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    do {
        try audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: soundFileURL, settings: recordSettings as! [String : AnyObject])
        audioRecorder?.prepareToRecord()
        audioRecorder?.meteringEnabled = true
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("audioSession error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

class func getDocumentsDirectory() -> String {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}

}
```

Then in the log it just prints this and I am making loud sounds and taling but it still doesn't change.

```
Average: Optional(-120.0) Peak: Optional(-120.0)
Average: Optional(-120.0) Peak: Optional(-120.0)
Average: Optional(-120.0) Peak: Optional(-120.0)
Average: Optional(-120.0) Peak: Optional(-120.0)
Average: Optional(-120.0) Peak: Optional(-120.0)
Average: Optional(-120.0) Peak: Optional(-120.0)
Average: Optional(-120.0) Peak: Optional(-120.0)
Average: Optional(-120.0) Peak: Optional(-120.0)
Average: Optional(-120.0) Peak: Optional(-120.0)
Average: Optional(-120.0) Peak: Optional(-120.0)
Average: Optional(-120.0) Peak: Optional(-120.0)
Average: Optional(-120.0) Peak: Optional(-120.0)
Average: Optional(-120.0) Peak: Optional(-120.0)
Average: Optional(-120.0) Peak: Optional(-120.0)
Average: Optional(-120.0) Peak: Optional(-120.0)
```

Comment: If you can target iOS 10 only, you might consider investigating Apple's new speech recognition API; https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/509/

Comment: The problem is that it will need an internet connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code, your file URL is wrong in someway, I changed the file URL to a temporary path as:

```
let pathStr = NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingString("sound.caf")
    let soundFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: pathStr)
```

and it works

```
Average: Optional(-27.2326279) Peak: Optional(-13.5865393)
Average: Optional(-33.1891823) Peak: Optional(-23.3389206)
Average: Optional(-49.0175018) Peak: Optional(-22.505867)
Average: Optional(-38.9896851) Peak: Optional(-18.3879299)
Average: Optional(-33.0929604) Peak: Optional(-20.2775478)
```